# Symfony / TWIG, Sort Array by Key

Tags: sorting, twig

Is it possible to sort an array by key without twig extension ?

I have an array like this :

```
{key1 : object1, key2 : object2...)
```

When i use `{% for t in tab|sort%}`, it give me an array sort by object ID and not by the key.

No way to do this without twig extension ?

Comment: Sort it in controller.

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with creating a twig extension ?

Comment: Oh yes ! I don't know why i absolutly want to do this with twig... I wiil sort in the controller, my bad sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a filter to do the sort by array key.

However, in case if you need to create a filter, you can do like this in your extended Twig extensions file,

Create the function,

```
public function ksort($array) {
    ksort($array);        
    return $array;
}
```

Hook the function in available filters,

```
public function getFilters() {
    $this->filters['ksort'] = new \Twig_SimpleFilter('ksort', array($this, 'ksort'));        
    return $this->filters;
}
```

And to call the filter,

```
{% for a in array | ksort %}
    <h2>{{ a }}</h2>   
{% endfor %}
```

Cheers

Comment: Why not just name the filter `ksort` instead of `twigKSort`? :D

Comment: @DarkBee : Well a good one. Just thought to make it stand out from Twig;s available filters, hence that's why I added that `twig` thing at the beginning. It would've been `custom` or something. I will make it more consisent, I will change it to `ksort` :D .Thank you :)